# Floated div overlapping unfloated div when below a certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've struck a problem with a project i'm working on, the problem i'm facing is that a div that's been floated right will overlap all elements below (It seems to treat the div like it has no content) The div in question is an animated logo I've made in adobe edge animate.

HTML --

```
<header>

    <div class="tophead">   </div>

    <div class="bottomhead">

        <div class="lefthead col-sm-3">
            <img src="includes/lefthead.svg"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="snippet">
            <h2>All Sections</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="righthead col-sm-3">
            <div id="Stage" class="EDGE-31003756">
            </div>

            <!--<img src="includes/righthead.svg"></img>-->
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</header>
```

CSS -

```
.lefthead {
padding-top:7px;
float:left !important;
}
.lefthead img {
max-height:77px;
min-height:60px;
}
.righthead {
padding-top:4px;
float:right !important;
}


.righthead.col-sm-3 {
max-height:70px;
min-height:60px;
}

.clear {
clear:both;
}
```

That's just a portion of the CSS as there is too much to paste.

A live version of the website can be found here -
http://www.mosesmartin.co.uk/digitalguys/home.php

The website will work fine up until you lower the width below 500px. After that the 3 header divs will change so that 'lefthead'and the 'snippet' are 50% width and the 'righthead' is central below.

I've tried using 'clear:both' but that won't seem to work (I might be using it wrong but i don't think i am)

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Just to get a better understanding, what exactly do you want to happen? Should the right floated div make the header bigger when it drops down?

Comment: Where should the logo go at < 500px? That will drive the solution.

Comment: Try to avoid using `!important` if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to make `<div class="righthead">` drop below the other divs without overlapping `<nav>`, change the `float` property of this media query ruleset from `none` to `left`:

**before:**

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .righthead {
    float: none !important;
  }
}
```

**after:**

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .righthead {
    float: left !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

***@Matt Smith*** has a solution that I overlooked and is a lot simpler than this, my bad.

---

Overall, you have more markup and styling than is needed which is making things a bit problematic for you. That said, the heart of the issue is with all the `height` declarations you have for `header` and `.bottomhead`. By constraining the height the content of the stacked elements are not able to stretch the height of the parent element.

```css
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    header {
        height: 80px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    header {
        height: 100px
    }
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}    
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .bottomhead {
        height: 80px;
    }
}
.bottomhead {
    height: 80px;
}
```

Remove or comment out all the `height` declarations mentioned above. That should get you what you are looking for or at least close. You can also get rid of your `.break` and `.clear` DIVs.

You will likely have to make an adjustment here and there after words.

You can simplify things in a number of places removing un-needed markup, i.e. adding a border to `.bottomhead` and remove `.tophead`.

```css
.bottomhead {
    border-top: 30px solid #20b148;
}
```

You might also find it useful to use the utility classes in Bootstrap like `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` to float elements left and right respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove all `height` from your header in your media query for that specific size. set it to `height:auto;` instead

Comment: That wasn't the problem but it was the cause of another problem i had, thankyou